# Xelement Search

Tags: c#, .net

Variable resp has following value.
System.Xml.Linq.XElement resp -           How do I get value of Statuscode in C# ?

Thanks!

**Value of resp is ( Did not include whole xml it's pretty long):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<fiAPI xmlns="http://integration.fiapi.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" xsi:schemalocation="http://integration.fiapi.com fiDocumentInquiry.xsd">
  <fiHeader Version="2.0">
    <Service Version="1.0" Name="FiservArchiveAccessAPI">
      <DateTime>2011-08-29T02:27:21-0-4:00</DateTime>
      <UUID>12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012</UUID>
    </Service>
    <Security>
      <AuthenticationMaterial>
        <PrincipalPWD></PrincipalPWD>
      </AuthenticationMaterial>
      <PrincipalID></PrincipalID>
    </Security>
    <Client Version="1.3">
      <VendorID>Vendor Name</VendorID>
      <AppID>CWS</AppID>
      <OrgID>44444451</OrgID>
      <SessionID>88888888-4444-4444-4444-123456789012</SessionID>
    </Client>
    <DataSource>
      <URI />
    </DataSource>
  </fiHeader>
  <Response TypeOfResponse="DocumentInquiryRs" TotalRows="2">
    <Status>
      <StatusCode>0</StatusCode>
      <Severity />
    </Status>
    <RequestEcho TypeOfRequest="DocumentInquiryRq" RequestID="123" Echo="True">
```

Comment: oh no @Henk: the answer is *allways* 42! so you want: public int GetResp(XElement element) { return 42; } :D

Comment: do give a more helpful comment: how are we supppost to guess the question from this? What is the "Statuscode" in your nasty long cryptic string? What format does it have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [Descendants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353813.aspx) method. Because your XML has a namespace make sure to include it when querying:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var resp = XElement.Load("test.xml");
        var statusCode = resp
            .Descendants("{http://integration.fiapi.com}StatusCode")
            .FirstOrDefault();
        if (statusCode != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(statusCode.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: now you got me interested ... can you read minds or where does this come from?

Comment: obvious ... some tipps for the lottery? ... how often did this question come up today/this week? ... oh sorry - guess I must be really sleepy by now ... just click edit and have a look huh? ... +1 for me beeing to dumb

Comment: @CKoenig, there are like gazillions of questions about XML parsing with C#.

Comment: no sorry - my first thought was that you knew because the same question was asked in the past ... never thought of looking into the "source-code" of the question ... only saw as Jimmy did his edit ....

Comment: It was Henk Holterman who discovered the secret XML ;) -- I just helped format the result a bit.